# How to get value of a Textbox from UserControl to MainPage

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl on my aspx file. On the main page I have a button. When Click on the button, I want to alert the UserControl's Textbox value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the UserControl's TextBox from the UserControl. Like this:

```
public TextBox txtBox
{
    get
    {
        return TextBox1;
    }
    set
    {
        TextBox1 = value;
    }
}
```

In this way, the TextBox becomes a public property of the UserControl, and it is accessible to any page using it. You can access to it from Javascript in the following way:

```
function getTextBoxAlert() {
    alert(document.getElementById("<%=MyTextBox1.txtBox.ClientID.ToString() %>").value);
}
```

Where `MyTextBox1` would be the name (ID) of the UserControl, and `txtBox` the name of the property.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onclientclick` property on your button -

```
onclientclick="alert(document.getElementById('<%= yourtextbox.ClientID %>').value)"
```

This presumes your button is asp.net control if it's just a HTML button you could do -

```
onclick="alert(document.getElementById('<%= yourtextbox.ClientID %>').value)"
```

Comment: Use this instead : `onclientclick="alert(document.getElementById('<%= yourtextbox.ClientID %>').value)"`. If you don't it wont works as the client id of the textbox will be a concatenation of all control's ancestors' ids. This applies if the control is a server control (not a simple `<input type="text">`

Comment: My textbox is DevExpress' ASPxTextbox. Does this solution works for it?

Comment: @erdincozdemir - I'm honestly not sure, could you try it and see?

Comment: I noticed that I made a mistake while giving ClientInstanceName to Textbox. Therefore ASPxTextbox.GetText() method didn't work. When I fix my mistake it works correctly. Thanks for answers.